# Hallar matriz traspuesta

Tags: c++

tengo que hallar la matriz traspuesta usando funciones booleanas, sin alterar la ubicación física  de los elementos, el ejercicio es este: Constrúyase un procedimiento:

```
void trasponer(void);
```

como método de la clase matriz_t, que, una  vez invocado, permita al usuario operar con la matriz original en formato traspuesto, independientemente de su dimensión.

Es importante notar que no se debe alterar en absoluto la ubicación física de los datos. Únicamente  debe incluirse como atributo una variable booleana denominada traspuesta_, alterar los métodos :

```
get_m(),
get_n(),
pos(matrix_inx_t i, matrix_inx_t j),
```

y alterar todas aquellos métodos en los que se acceda a algún elemento y se haga referencia a la dimensión de la matriz. Inclúyase en un programa principal las siguientes líneas:

```
matrix_t A;

cout << endl;
A.read(cin);
cout << "---  MATRIZ ORIGINAL  ---" << endl;
A.write();

cout << "---  MATRIZ ORIGINAL TRASPUESTA---" << endl;
A.trasponer();
A.write();
```

Si me podrían dar una idea por favor

Comment: Bienvenido Robert. Veo que no has seguido el [tour]. Te lo recomiendo mucho así como tambión [ask]. Otra recomación más es cuidar el formato. Ya he aplicado el formato de código a una parte. Te sugiero que apliques el formato de cita al texto que no sea de tu autoría y hacer la atribución correspondiente de forma apropiada.

Comment: Los trabajos académicos deben tener una demostración de lo que has intentado. Basicamente has puesto lo que te ha dado el profesor para que te lo resolvamos aquí. Si haces el recorrido como te han indicado verás que esta es una de las normas del sitio.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n totalmente de acuerdo y, para evitar malentendidos, voto para cerrar esta pregunta a la espera de que se añada código que demuestre que no estás pidiendo que te hagamos los deberes.

Comment: Igualmente voto por cerrar esta pregunta, solo se está pidiendo una respuesta a un problema (que parece una asignación de una materia) sin mostrar ningún código hecho para solucionarlo.